# Get the index of a unique character in a table (list of lists)?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of r lists of r elements each.
Let's say `r=3` then I have something that looks like this:

```
list=[["o","o","o"],["o","i","o"],["o","o","o"]]
```

I would like, using the method """`list.index(item)`""", to get the index of the "i" elements inside this list. So as a result I should get something I imagine like (x,y) with x for the xth sublist and y for the yth element inside the xth sublist ((1,1) in this case).

I can join the code of my program (game) if you need it later.

Comment: Will the size of the lists always be of length r?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution that finds an index for all values in the nested list, here is a function for you:

```
def find_indexes(needle, lst):
    return [(lst_idx, sub_idx) for lst_idx, sublst in enumerate(lst) 
                               for sub_idx, i in enumerate(sublst) 
                                   if i == needle]
```

You can use as follows:

```
>>> lst = [["o","a","o"],["a","i","o"],["o","o","a"]]
>>> find_indexes('a', lst)
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `try` to find the index row by row:

```
def findI(rows):
    for i,row in enumerate(rows):
        try:
            return (i,row.index("i"))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

For example:

```
>>> x =[["o","o","o"],["o","i","o"],["o","o","o"]]
>>> findI(x)
(1, 1)
```

Comment: I finally came up with something that does the trick too, but it takes more lines of code than yours. Yours looks cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Here is what I got:

def indxi(): #Recuperer coordonnees de "i" dans place_objects()
____x=place_objects()
____for i in range(len(x)):
________if "i" in x[i]:
____________a=i
____o=x[a].index("i")
____return (a,o)

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment, I don't know yet how to correctly insert code in "comments".

Comment: Surround code by backquotes  -- though you really can't do multi-line code in comments.

Comment: You should catch the specific exception: `except ValueError:`

Comment: @brianpck With further thought that it is definitely a good idea. It is always somewhat dangerous to catch all errors and possibly prevent error handlers in the calling code from receiving the errors. In this case there is probably little real danger, but good design should still be followed as much as possible. I edited it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this:

```
list=[["o","o","o"],["o","i","o"],["o","o","o"]]
f = [sublist for sublist in list if element in sublist][0]
print(list.index(f), f.index(element))
```

That `[0]` is because it will return something like `[[a,b]]`, because is  like a filter. But I need `[a, b]`. Hope it helps. The problem with this is that it fails when the element isn't in list.